# Double integral steps to solve

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm working on the following integral:
$$\iint\limits_D\frac{x}{x^2+2y^2}dxdy$$

Over $1<x^2+y^2<4$ and $0<x<y$

This is the integral I got from this, that I'm trying to solve, but I don't know how I should continue:
$$\int\limits_{1}^{2}\int\limits_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x\cos y}{x^2\cos^2 y+2x^2\sin^2 y}dxdy$$

Comment: Why don't you try simplifying the integrand and using the property that sin^2+cos^2=1?

Comment: How can I do that when its 2 (sin y)^2?

Comment: When you are using polar coordinates you should take in account jacobian.

Answer (score 1):

See, please, how the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) you forgot, helps in the numerator of the fraction
$$\int\frac{r\cdot r\cos \phi}{r^2\cos^2 \phi+2r^2\sin^2 \phi}d\phi=\int\frac{ r^2\cos \phi}{r^2+r^2\sin^2 \phi}d\phi=\int\frac{\cos \phi}{1+\sin^2 \phi}d\phi = \arctan(\sin \phi)+C$$
Hope, you will be able to finish now.